# How to use \begin{gather} to restart number ordering?

Tags: math-mode, numbering

I'm new to LaTeX and I was wondering if there is a way to restart the number ordering when using the gather function?

I used gather twice but in different lemmas so I want the ordering to restart to (1) instead of continuing where it left off.

Thank you!

Comment: it uses the `equation` counter so you could reset that but better is to declare that equation is reset in lemma usiing \counterwithin

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is not very clear.  `Gather` is not a function but  an equauions environment. Could you post a small code showing what you tried and what exactly you want?

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure if my code will help visualize my goal but utilizing 'gather' allows an ordering of numbers to the right such as (1), (2), etc. I want to use gather twice without the order of numbers continuing from the first use. Currently, my first gather code has 3 lines so my second gather code continues off at (4). Sorry if this is confusing!

Comment: You might use something like `\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{counterwithin{equation}{lemma}}`. For lemma , say, 4, equations within this lemma would be numbered (4.1), (4.2), &c.